# what to check when can't connect the port of Squid proxy server on remote server

Tags: firewall, port, squid, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I want to connect from local pc(Windows10) to the specific port on the remote server(Windows server2019). The port is of Squid proxy server.

But, I tried checking with PowerShell command on the local server if the connection works. It can connect to the remote server itself, but can't connect to the port on it.

Also, I tried checking with PowerShell command on the remote server if the connection works even from the remote server to the remote server itself. And it worked. The remote server can connect to the port of Squid proxy server on itsself.

I also checked the firewall setting of the port of the Squid proxy server. And I think that it is open.

What else can I check in order to connect to the port?

The commands on PowerShell on the local PC and those results below:

```
Test-NetConnection XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
-->PingSucceeded          : True

Test-NetConnection XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -Port 3128
-->PingSucceeded          : True
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

The commands on PowerShell on the remote server and those results below:

```
Test-NetConnection XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -Port 3128
-->TcpTestSucceeded       : True
```

The image of The firewall setting of the Squid server port on the remote server:

[image of the firewall setteing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZG6K.png)

Answer (score 0):

The test clearly shows that your host cannot connect to the TCP/3128 on the remote. So either your host is blocking its packets coming to the remote TCP/3128 address (doubt that) or the remote packet filter is blocking them on arrival (most likely).

Check the packet filter on the remote.

Comment: Thank you. How to check the packet fileter on Windows Server2019?